# GNU make, how to determine a path is a file or a directory?

Tags: makefile

From some path, I use

```
PATHS = $(wildcard $(SOME_PATH)/*)
```

to get all sub-paths.

I need to know whether it's a file or a directory.

How to do it in make?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

John Marshall has a way that will work, but there's a safer way.  All directories always have a single entry that is well known, and that's ".".  So, what you have to do is:

```
PATHS := $(wildcard $(SOME_PATH)/*)
DIRS := $(patsubst %/.,%,$(wildcard $(addsuffix /.,$(PATHS))))
FILES := $(filter-out $(DIRS),$(PATHS))
```

The wildcard will match all directories, and only directories, since only directories contain ".".  This is robust.

Yehnan's way works as well but is less efficient because you're invoking a shell for each element in PATHS.  Most likely this won't impact your runtime much overall but if it can be done inside make rather than by running shell, I would prefer that.  Also it helps portability to avoid $(shell ...).

Answer (score 4):

```
DIRS  := $(patsubst %/,%,$(filter %/,$(wildcard $(SOME_PATH)/*/)))
FILES := $(filter-out $(DIRS),$(wildcard $(SOME_PATH)/*))
```

It appears that it can also be done with just one `wildcard` as follows:

```
ENTRIES := $(wildcard $(SOME_PATH)/*/)
DIRS  := $(patsubst %/,%,$(filter %/,$(ENTRIES)))
FILES := $(filter-out %/,$(ENTRIES))
```

but I am less convinced of the robustness of depending on `$(wildcard */)` to produce entries for files, seeing as they don't actually match the requested pattern (i.e., such entries don't have a trailing slash).

GNU Make 3.82 does produce such entries, but it seems a bit like a bug rather than a feature.

Answer (score 1):

```
PATHS = $(wildcard $(SOME_PATH)/*)
DIRPATHS = $(foreach dir, $(wildcard $(PATHS)/*), $(shell test -d $(dir) && echo $(dir)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Code below works under a standard `bash` and print for each found element if it's a directory:

```
PATHS=$(wildcard *)
for f in $(PATHS); do \
    if test -d $$f; then echo "$$f: DIR"; fi; \
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not strictly answering the question but if you only want a variable containing all files only, then `find` might be even faster I think even though it creates another process and does not rely on make functionality only.

```
FILES := $(shell find $(SOME_PATH) -type -f)
```

One advantage is that you can even use multiple paths as input (i.e. `SOME_PATH`).